# 64 bit assembly idiv operation isn't behaving as expected

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64

Hi I am just playing around in 64 bit assembly but my compiler keeps throwing :(13: Invalid combination of opcode and operands) can anyone explain why this is happening thanks.

```
10:  myfunc:
11:    mov  rax, rcx
12:    xor  rdx, rdx
13:    idiv 10
14:    mov rax, rdx
15:    ret
```

For people that doesn't read assembly this is similar to:

```
int myfunc(int a)
{
    return a % 10;
}
```

Comment: Consult an instruction set reference. There is no `idiv` that takes an immediate operand. You need to load into a register.

Comment: Most instructions don't take an immediate operand, it just seems that way because a bunch of very common ones do. Also, remainder by a constant is usually not implemented as an `idiv` but as magic number division for example: https://godbolt.org/g/OngMiM

Answer (score 3):

As [Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester) mentioned. The idiv operation doesn't take immediate values as operands , the following code will work as expected.

```
10:  myfunc:
11:     mov  rax, rcx
12:     xor  rdx, rdx
13:     mov  rbx, 10
14:     idiv rbx
15:     mov rax, rdx
16:     ret
```

Comment: This still has a more subtle bug: you're doing signed division after *zero*-extending the arg to 128-bit.  If you actually wanted signed division, you should do `cdq`/`idiv`, otherwise you should do `xor edx,edx` / `div rcx` after `mov rax,rcx`.

Comment: Also this violates the calling convention: you modify the caller's RBX.  Unlike RAX, RCX, and RDX which are call-clobbered in the standard calling conventions, RBX is call-preserved.  So don't touch RBX, reuse RCX instead: `mov rax,rcx` / `cdq` / `mov ecx, 10` / `idiv rcx` / `mov rax, rdx`.

Comment: Correction, `cqo`/`idiv rcx` for 64-bit signed division.  `cdq`/`idiv ecx` for 32-bit operand-size, dividing EDX:EAX by ECX.